# Is it possible to retrieve the compression level from a png image?

Tags: compression, png

In my project we deal with png images. In order to create (encode) and read (decode) png images we use libpng.
From libpng it is possible to specify the compression level using `png_set_compression_level()`, and effectively we can see some changes in the size of the images which make us think that the compression was done correctly.

But in order to properly and reliably test it I need (and I would have expected, for consistency) a `png_get_compression_level()` function that tells you which compression level was used to create that particular png file. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Is there a way to get this information from the png image (if possible via libpng it is better, but also any other way would be good enough for me) ?

Answer (score 0):

try ExifTool.  I have not yet.

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html

locate PNG syntax for tags

download, no install needed for command line operation
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
extract
read help

run exiftool from cmd shell with tags and file name

- procedure may depend on PNG format file version so read command help details (extensive)

Comment: I understand but PNG format details are missing and a complete solution is within grasp of the competent user, depending on PNG spec versions of files being read.

Answer (score 0):

According to the zlib specification ([RFC-1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)), the zlib datastream within a PNG file contains a two-bit "FLEVEL" flag:

```
 FLEVEL (Compression level)
 These flags are available for use by specific compression
 methods.  The "deflate" method (CM = 8) sets these flags as
 follows:

    0 - compressor used fastest algorithm [levels 0, 1]
    1 - compressor used fast algorithm    [levels 2-5]
    2 - compressor used default algorithm [level 6]
    3 - compressor used maximum compression, slowest algorithm [levels 7-9]
```

pngcheck checks FLEVEL and reports it like this:

```
pngcheck -v rose.png
[...]
chunk IDAT at offset 0x00073, length 6742
  zlib: deflated, 16K window, maximum compression
```

While this won't distinguish among all 10 possible compression levels, it could be the basis for creating a libpng png_get_compression_level() function that would at least tell you something.

Comment: You can just reencode with ffmpeg and check it. But, please note that -pred mixed in ffmpeg is a different beast alltogether. P.S. I know the guy is dead. 